# change Tabs on user type

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation, tabnavigator

i have 2 types of users : 1 - Customers 2 - Expert
after user logins to system they see diffrent Tabs here is my Navigator

```
export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
Splash: {
    screen: Splash
},
Login: {
    screen: Login
},
Register: {
    screen: Register
},
Verify: {
    screen: Verify
},
Tabs: {
    screen: TabNavigator
}
}, { headerMode: 'none' });
```

and this is my tabNavigator

```
Setting: {
    screen: settingNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Icon name="cog" size={20} color={tintColor}/>
        )
    }
},
MyProjects: {
    screen: myProjectsNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Icon name="th-list-1" size={20} color={tintColor}/>
        )
    }
},
Requests: {
    screen: requestsNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Icon name="chat-inv" size={20} color={tintColor}/>
        )
    }
},
Customers: {
    screen: customersNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Icon name="users" size={20} color={tintColor}/>
        )
    }
},

Profile: {
    screen: profileNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Icon name="user" size={20} color={tintColor}/>
        )
    }
}
}, {
tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
animationEnabled: true,
tabBarOptions: {
    showIcon: true,
    showLabel: false,
    activeTintColor: '#1e87f0',
    inactiveTintColor: '#808080',
    animationEnabled: true,
    indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    style: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderColor: '#C1CED8'
    }
},
headerMode: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'screen' : 'none',
lazy: false
});
```

now if userType is customer he/she should see only Setting and myProjects ,
and if userType is Expert he/she should see all 5 tabs,

im trying to return 2 diffrent Navigators depend on userType something like this

```
if (user.type === 'expert') {
    return <ExpertNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state: nav })}/>;
} else {
    return <CustomerNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state: nav })}/>;
}
```

the diffrence between ExpertNavigator and CustomerNavigator is only Their Tabs but when i login with a Customer User i got an error with the title of there is no route defined for Requests Tab

how can i implement this ?

Comment: Could you share ExportNavigator and CustomerNavigator code ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: for now I'm creating two TabNavigators then on userType change it navigates to another router